# CF ORM - EntityLoad filterCriteria using IN clause

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

How would I do the following with CF ORM?

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id in ('3,7,12,5');
```

I tried

```
EntityLoad("products", { id in ('#productIDlist#') });
```

But no Joy.. getting error: `Invalid construct: Either argument or name is missing. When using named parameters to a function, each parameter must have a name.`

.. I am sure this is straight forward, but  I can't work out how to do this, and can't find any samples or docs.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use HQL. It would look like:

```
ormExecuteQuery( "FROM products WHERE id IN ('#productIDlist#') " );
```

You can also use parametize the query (similar to cfqueryparam).

Comment: @SamFarmer How would it look parameterized? ormExecuteQuery( "FROM products WHERE id IN (':list_here') ", {list_here=productIDlist} ); ? I'm attempting something similar, but I keep getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* to use HQL, you could also use [criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html). Frankly, I don't see much advantage using HQL vs plain SQL, but criteria is a powerful, flexible API rather than yet another parsed language.

Comment: Josh, thanks for the tip.  I did a bit of reading up on HQL.. running this through ormExecuteQuery does get the data via the Entity in Hibernate, with all the benefits that brings with it.  Plain SQL just access the DB directly.  I had a read up on 'criteria' link you posted.. interesting.. will do some more reading, but at this point I couldn't see how it would acheive current objectives without getting too involved.. will do some more reading up on that one though I think.  Thanks!